# Trying to get property 'cname' of non-object Laravel php 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, object, error-handling, laravel-5.8

I am learning laravel 5.8, and I am building a job portal website.

My question is why this error happens. I have already checked my table, and obviously, I have a column cname(company name) in the company table. And also I have an object.

Following is my code. I am really glad if someone helps me out.

This code is for identifying the user is a job seeker or an employer.
I would like to register as a job seeker.

[this is my error page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Em0.png)

app.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    @if(Auth::user()->user_type='company')
                                        {{Auth::user()->company->cname}}
                                    @else
                                        {{Auth::user()->name}}
                                    @endif
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
```

user.php

```
use App\Profile;
use App\Company;

public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
        }

    public function company(){
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
        }
```

web.php

```
Route::POST('employer/register', 'EmployerRegisterController@employerRegister')->name('emp.register');

Route::view('employer/register','auth.employer-register')->name('employer.register');
```

CompanyController.php

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        Company::where('user_id',$user_id)->update([
            'address'=>request('address'),
            'phone'=>request('phone'),
            'website'=>request('website'),
            'slogan'=>request('slogan'),
            'description'=>request('description')
        ]);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','Company Successfully Updated !');
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the full error stack.

Comment: Can you update your question with output of this `dd(Auth::user()->company)`

Comment: @DrakulaPredator that is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error throw because `Auth::user()->company` is `Null`. Use Ternary operator when try to get relation attribute like this `Auth::user()->company->cname ?? ''`

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        @if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'company')
            {{Auth::user()->company->cname ?? ''}}
        @else
            {{Auth::user()->name}}
        @endif
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

the results dont seems to return anything. because of the single = instead of ==  try something like this:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    @if(Auth::user()->user_type=='company')
                                        {{Auth::user()->company->cname}}
                                    @else
                                        {{Auth::user()->name}}
                                    @endif
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
```